# leave for having vs change for having

Tags: american-english

**Are these idiomatic? if not, why?**

2 coworkers are talking....

**Person 1**: I'm tired of working for other people. I wish I could have the money to start up my own business and be my own boss.

**Person 2**: Would really **leave** your position **for** **having/starting up** your own business? Would you **change** your job **for** having your own store?

Answer (score 1):

> Would **you** really leave your position **to start** your own business?

If we said "leave your job for another job", the other job is seen as a relatively static thing that already exists. You would be leaving your job **for** this thing. Starting your own business is an activity that you would be doing, so we would say, "to do", i.e. "to start your own business".

> Would you change your job for having your own store?

This doesn't make too much sense because you are not changing your job (i.e. for another job, in the same sense). So it would then become:

> Would you **leave** your job for having your own store?

Similar to the above, we wouldn't use "for". Also, I feel that having your own store isn't quite as certain as the opportunity to start your own business, which is a bit more of an abstract idea anyway (it could mean many things). So I would really phrase this as:

> Would you leave your job **so you could own** your own store?

The use of the word "could" implies that this would be a possibility, an potential opportunity that would open up to you once you've left your job.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The verb *leave* can take a *for* phrase indicating the destination. This can be a real place:

> They left for Venice.
>
> I'm leaving for the coast tomorrow.

Or a notional place (like a job):

> She left for a much better job.

But it can't be an *-ing* clause.

There's not really any reason for this (most *-ing* clauses don't make sense as destinations, but some might do): it's just a property which the verb *leave* happens to have.